# How to properly stop all the threads in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In the code below, I maintain the "isFound" boolean variable to determine whether a thread should run or not. However, when I set the "isFound" to true. My threads will run exactly one more time. In other words, they will not stop properly which also causes the UI to not update the Textview properly. I guess this is due to some synchronized problems but I am not sure how to deal with it and I have tried using a synchronized block but it still does not work.

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView message;
    private TextView magicNumDisplay;
    private boolean isFound = false;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification notifyDetail;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if (isMagic(msg.what)) {
                isFound = true;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                magicNumDisplay.setText("The magic number is " + msg.what);
                handler.removeMessages(0);
                message.setText("A magic number s found");
                Intent intent = new Intent("MAGIC_NUMBER");
                intent.putExtra("THREAD_NAME", msg.obj.toString());
                intent.putExtra("MAGIC_NUMBER", String.valueOf(msg.what));
                sendBroadcast(intent);

            } else {
                message.setText("Finding a magic number...");
            }

        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        magicNumDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magic_num_display);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("MAGIC_NUMBER");
        BroadcastReceiver receiver =  new MagicNumberReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(backgroundTask, "First");
        Thread secondThread = new Thread(backgroundTask, "Second");
        firstThread.start();
        secondThread.start();
    }

    public boolean isMagic(int num) {
        return (num % 7 == 0 && isLastDigitEqualTwo(num));
    }

    public boolean isLastDigitEqualTwo(int num) {
        String numString = String.valueOf(num);
        return Integer.parseInt(numString.substring(numString.length() - 1))==2;
    }

    Runnable backgroundTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                while (!isFound) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    int number = (int) (Math.random() * 9999);
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(number, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    Log.e(Thread.currentThread().getName(), "The number is :" + number);
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                }

        }
    };
    public class MagicNumberReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context localContext, Intent callerIntent) {
            String threadName = callerIntent.getStringExtra("THREAD_NAME");
            String magicNum = callerIntent.getStringExtra("MAGIC_NUMBER");

            Log.e("Magic", "Thread name:"+threadName+" Magic Number:"+magicNum);

            int MAGIC_NUMBER_NOTIFICATION_ID=200;
            notifyDetail = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle("Magic Number")
                    .setContentText("Thread Name: " + threadName + ".  Magic Number: " + magicNum+".")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.droid)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setLights(Integer.MAX_VALUE,  500,  500)
                    .build();
            notificationManager.notify(MAGIC_NUMBER_NOTIFICATION_ID,notifyDetail);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because you sleep at the start of the while loop? If it's found while it's sleeping it'll finish that loop? What if you sleep at the end of the while block?

Comment: `isFound` variable is used by three different threads at the same time. You should synchronize its access, or else you application may break or worse

Comment: @nandsito what would be the preferred way to do the synchronization? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there isn't a preferred way to sync threads, but there are several ways to do it, and you can pick the one you feel most comfortable with. For example, synchronized statements, synchronized methods, serialized access, guarded blocks... i suggest you to spend some time studying concurrency https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html